# How to convert a PDE from cartesian to spherical coordinates?

Tags: differential-equations, coordinate-transformation

I am investigating solutions to $\Delta u - x\cdot \nabla u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I would like to convert this equation from cartesian to spherical coordinates in mathematica. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: In “Mathematica” or in “mathematical”? If the former, have you seen TransformedField[]? I don’t think it works on an indefinite $n$, however.

Comment: Also, how is spherical coordinates defined for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @xzczd: See "Spherical coordinates" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) for info.

Comment: You can find the answer at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: @DanielHuber: Only for three dimensions.